# Copy everything is single folder from x months back

Tags: linux, bash, cp

How do I copy every file in one folder without copying the sub folder contents. The sub folder contents are overwriting the parent files (same names)

```
-images
  .image1.png
  ..
  -thumbs
    .image1.png
```

I have tried `find . -mtime -120 -exec cp {} /dest/images \;` sub folder `thumbs` contents overwrite the current files in current folder.

`find . -mtime -120 -exec cp {} /images \;`

Comment: Trying to copy files from 4 months back to another destination. But the smaller images (thumbs) are overwriting then originals. -type f overwrites still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is just to omit the subfolders' contents, you can specify a certain depth to use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -120 -exec cp {} /images \;
```

This will ignore everything that isn't in the current folder. There's also `-mindepth`, which is fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: Why would `-maxdepth 1` work vs `-maxdepth 0`? Also the output shows `cp: omitting direction '.'` - `cp: omitting directory './thumb'` but the outcome is correct.

Comment: `cp` will not copy directories unless you use `-r`, but it will let you know that you are telling it to copy some directories. You can omit those by using `-type f` to only pass files to `cp`.

Comment: `-maxdepth 1` goes 1 level into the argument. You are passing a directory, so it looks at the contents of that directory. `-maxdepth 0` goes 0 deep, meaning it will check if the argument passed matches the specs. `find mypath/ -name "*path" -maxdepth 0` is a valid command that would check if the argument provided matches the constraints given; it would not check the cotents of `mypath/` at all

Answer (score 1):

Use `-maxdepth 2`:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -mtime -120 -exec cp {} /images \;
```

From [`man find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

```
   -maxdepth levels
          Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of
          directories below the starting-points.  -maxdepth 0 means only
          apply the tests and actions to the starting-points themselves.
```